# How can I put a sed command into a while loop?

Tags: unix, sed

Hoping someone kind can help me pls!

I have an file `input.list`:

```
/scratch/user/IFS/IFS001/IFS003.GATK.recal.bam
/scratch/user/IFS/IFS002/IFS002.GATK.recal.bam
/scratch/user/EGS/ZFXHG22/ZFXHG22.GATK.recal.bam
```

and I want to extract the bit before `.GATK.recal.bam` - I have found a solution for this:

```
sed 's/\.GATK\.recal\.bam.*//' input.list | sed 's@.*/@@'
```

I now want to incorporate this into a while loop but it's not working... please can someone take a look and guide me where I'm doing wrong. My attempt is below:

```
while read -r line; do ID=${sed 's/\.GATK\.recal\.bam.*//' $line | sed 's@.*/@@'}; sbatch script.sh $ID; done < input.list
```

Apologies for the easy Q...

Comment: `$line` is not a file. Use `$()` not `${}`. Quote use of variables: `"$line"`,`"$ID"`, etc. You can also use single sed with no while: `<input.list sed -e 's/\.GATK\.recal\.bam.*//' -e 's@.*/@@' | xargs -I@ sbatch script.sh @`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in straight up `bash` (If you're using that shell; `ksh93` and `zsh` will be very similar) no `sed` required:

```sh
while read -r line; do
    id="${line##*/}" # Remove everything up to the last / in the string
    id="${id%.GATK.recal.bam}" # Remove the trailing suffix
    sbatch script.sh "$id"
done < input.list
```

At the very least you can use a single `sed` call per line:

```sh
id=$(sed -e 's/\.GATK\.recal\.bam$//' -e 's@.*/@@' <<<"$line")
```

or with plain `sh`

```sh
id=$(printf "%s\n" "$line" | sed -e 's/\.GATK\.recal\.bam$//' -e 's@.*/@@')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the output of the `sed` command as input for the loop:

```
sed 'COMMAND' input.file | while read -r id ; do
    some_command "${id}"
done
```

Instead of the loop, also `xargs` could be used:

```
sed 'COMMAND' input.file | xargs -n1 some_command
```

---

ps: GNU sed supports to execute the result of a `s` operation as a command. I wouldn't recommend to use this in production, for portability reasons at least, but it's worth mention probably:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\.GATK\.recal\.bam.*/sbatch script.sh \1/e' input.file
```